# Extending class A with class B, but can't reach attributes of class A in class B methods

Tags: java, attributes, extends

So I if I have two classes like this:

```
public class A extends B{

    public String name = "Alpha"

}

public class B{

    public void revealAName(){
        print(this.name);
    }
}

main(){
A newA = new A();
newA.revealName();
}
```

In this case Eclipse says that the attribute name doesn't exist. Why does it say that? why cant I use class A-objects' attributes when I'm inside class B's methods? How can I fix it?

Comment: you can fix it by deriving B from A and not A from B

Comment: yeah but then i cant use A objects to use B methods...

Comment: to put it another way: you can't use fields of a derived class in a super class

Comment: The question doesn't make sense. How can `B` know it's an instance of `A`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`B` doesn't know anything about attributes in `A`, both classes could be compiled separately.

But if you change it so that `B extends A`, you can access `name` from the derived class (`B`):

```
class A {
    String name = "Alpha";
}

class B extends A {
    public void revealAName(){
        print(this.name);
    }
}
```

```
A a = new A();
a.name; // OK
a.revealName(); // not OK

B b = new B();    
b.name; // OK
b.revealName(); // OK
```

See also the [Oracle tutorial on inheritance](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/subclasses.html)

Answer (score 1):

First of all, there should be only one public class that should contain the main method.
Secondly, You are using inheritance. So, You have to give access modifier of your base class's variables to "protected" in order to access in your child classes. So, it should be:

protected String name = "Alpha";

because "default" access modifier won't allow access for child class. From [controlling access to members of class](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html)

```
 Modifier       Class   Package Subclass World   
 public         Y       Y       Y        Y  
 protected      Y       Y       Y        N  
 no modifier    Y       Y       N        N  
 private        Y       N       N        N
```

Another thing, you used 'this.name' that is trying to get the 'name' variable of class B. That's why it's showing error.

While using inheritance, You can directly use the parent class's variable without using any object reference OR You can use "super" for object reference in case of duplicate variable names.
[You can refer this image in case of doubt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u1vFu.png)..

Hope, It would be clear now.

Comment: I've merged my answer into yours since yours is more detailed. Feel free to rollback the edit if you do not approve.

Comment: Thanks...Austin. It's perfectly fine. +1 for that